# AdMob Banner above Tabs in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, admob

[image]

I currently have an AdMob banner underneath my ViewPager TabPager as shown in the image, and I would like the banner to be above the ViewPager. I add in the banner programatically, and have set the ViewPager as the only element inside a RelativeLayout.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding the Admob Banner to the RelativeLayout in activity_main.xml

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "ADMOB_ID");

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, R.id.layout);

layout.addView(adView, params);
```

Comment: Did you got the answer for that without using a TabHost, as the TabHost is already been depricated.

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela Yes I used TabHost even though it was depricated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Tab layout is attached to the Action Bar. If you would like to show an ad above the tabs, you'll be better off using TabHost in your xml layout.

Ex.:

- Layout

  - AdView
  - Tabs
  - Content (pager)

EDIT: check out the video i linked in comments

and your xml should look something like this

`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
```

/*

TAB 1 CONTENT HERE

*/

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
```

/*

TAB 2 CONTENT HERE

*/

```
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>`
```

Comment: What changes would allow me to do so? This is my first time with Tabs

Comment: This video is very useful and this dude explains pretty well imo. [Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5LrdSQrWEI)

Comment: Isn't TabHost deprecated?

Comment: Uhm, never heard of it getting deprecated. I might be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 1):

As i can see you're using ACTIONBAR TABs according to description provide in documentation the tabs are the immediate child of Actionbar So its not possible in case you're using Actionbar tabs.

you can do what you wanted using TABHOST and tablayout.

Comment: Even though TabHost is deprecated?

Comment: @clever_trevor ya i knew `tabhost` is deprecated but in my view its the only way to get what you want working

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry for this very late reply. I had this problem once and i solved this way:

in your **activity_main.xml** you need to add **android:layout_below** in `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` so that ads is above viewpager. And it will be as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ad_view" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it will help someone